# How can I fill these UV squares with the Fill tool in Texture Paint?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

[image]

I'm trying to reskin and repaint some 3D models, but the Brush isn't very efficient and bleeds over the edges. Is there any way I can fill the UV squares with the Fill tool in Texture Paint mode?